# Regex qoute multi level C#/VB

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I need help with the following

> "this is a test "inside another, "test, with comma""","test","test"

I am trying to archive this result

> this is a test "inside another, "test, with comma""
>   
> test
>   
> test

This is the far I got

```
[^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'
```

I tried various solutions and nothing worked can someone help me please?

Comment: Well then show us what you tried.

Comment: [^\\s\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)' this is the most near I got

Comment: Can you _explain_ what you are trying to accomplish? How do you plan to "archive" the result?

Comment: I would like to split the three results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the soloution i came up with:

```
\"(?<m>.*?)\",|\"(?<m>[^\"]*?)\"
```

According to http://regexstorm.net/tester it works with the given example.

The matching group m contains the results.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was looking for